# Server receives half of the POST Request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, ubuntu, post

I have a Laravel 5.1 app in Ubuntu Server with Apache. The problem is that with AJAX I send a POST Request, and in the server I don't receive the complete values. I debugged the ajax and the values are OK and I can see them all, but in Laravel I can see I don't receive all the values when I do:

```
dd($_POST);
```

The value I send is an Array with 3 short strings, and with an array of 655 positions with 4 text inside each position. What I mean is, it's a big array what I send!!. But how can I solve this? So that I can receive big values?.

Thank you,

Comment: Check `max_input_vars` in php.ini, it's often limited to 1000

Comment: PHP does have a limitation of POST values. You can change it in the php.ini. Although texts rarely reach that threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Request::all();
```

Remember to add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` before your controller class

Comment: Happens the same, the request is not complete

Comment: @JoaquinColella try this instead( maybe you don't see whole $_POST because of white space): `<pre><?php var_dump($_POST); ?></pre>`

Comment: Keeps the same. The problem is that with dd($_POST) I also can see that the length of the array is 201 instead of 650.

Comment: @JoaquinColella check in your php.ini file line that starts with `max_input_vars` as i remember the default size is 200, increase it to 1000 and try again